# C# Call generic-type interface method with a Type object

Tags: c#, design-patterns, reflection

I have an interface

```
public interface IDefLoad<TType> 
{
    void Load<TType>(TType Type)
}
```

And a partial class inheriting

```
public partial class Defs : IDefLoad<Car>
{
    public void Load<Car>(Car Type) 
    {
        . . .
    }
}
```

But, the only way I can call these methods is with soft types through this section of code with Defs.Prepare()

```
public void Prepare() 
{
    Assembly Assembly;
    Type[] Types;
    Type Type;

    for (int i = 0; i < ExecutionAssemblies.Length; i++)
    {
        Types = (Assembly = ExecutionAssemblies[i]).GetTypes();

        for (int k = 0; k < Types.Length; k++)
        {
            Type = Types[k];

            // Type handling here
        }
    }
}
```

How can I check a given Type is that of typeof(Car), and then check if Defs has inherited from IDefLoad with that type?

On top of that, is there a better way to do this? I havent benchmarked but I have a feeling this is not very effecient. My end goal is to be able to scan current loaded assemblies and if theres a method created to load this specific type within Defs, it will call it.

So far i've gotten up to here, but I dont know how to call the method

```
            foreach (Type Interface in Defs.GetType().GetInterfaces()) 
            {
                if (Interface.IsGenericType && Interface.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDefLoad<>))
                {
                    Type TargetType = Interface.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                }
            }
```